# Datomic query performance on multiple inputs as fast as on a single input?

Tags: distributed, sharding, querying, datomic

Datomic allows us to [use multiple inputs](http://docs.datomic.com/query.html#sec-3-8), i.e. multiple datomic servers, in the same query.

As queries are [performed locally in the peers, using the actual db indexes inside the peer](http://docs.datomic.com/architecture.html), it seems running queries that join data from multiple datomic servers could potentially be almost, if not as fast as doing a similar join on a single datomic server.

Is that the case or is there a qualitative difference of how the query engine works when using multiple sources?

(If there is none, we could get around the fact that all writes in a datomic server have to go through a single transactor, by doing sharding to scale write performance arbitrarily. The benefit over RDBMS sharding would be querying performance and efficiency when joining)

**Edit:**

It turns out, even inside a single datomic server, [not all queries are equally fast](http://docs.datomic.com/schema.html#sec-2):

> Entities you'll often query across - like the community-related entities in our sample data - should be in the **same partition to increase query performance**.

So let me rephrase: **Are queries across datomic servers roughly as fast** and efficient (memory, cpu usage, network) **as queries across partitions on a single datomic server?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Datomic's query engine does not care where the underlying index segments come from, so a query that used indexes from multiple different systems pays no penalty compared to a query that is using indexes from a single system.

That said, you will have to organize your data in such a way that there are useful attributes to join across the N systems to do anything interesting.  This could have performance impacts, e.g. choosing larger value types than simple entity ids would reduce the amount of data that could fit in cache.